# Can I read Knapp's Basic algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am undergraduate student who learning Analysis now. (Self study)

After learning Linear algebra I am going to Study Algebra

I want to use Knapp's basic and advanced algebra volumes.

Can I read this basic algebra?

If it would be tough, what should I use for supplement?

or I should read undergraduate algebra book?

Comment: you can check this book : https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~aknapp/download/b2-alg-inside.pdf

Comment: No one is holding a gun against your head stopping you from reading whatever, is there?

Comment: I meant Do i can understand this book properly.

Comment: Try A BRIEF SURVEY OF MODERN ALGEBRA
Birkhoff, Garrett and MacLane, Saunders .